# randint doesn't want to multiply with an int and then subtract from an int

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm a beginner in python 3.x and for some reason my randint doesn't want to work like it used to before. 
I have a score which was supposed to be subtracted by a random number between 1 and 5 multiplied with your attack value.
This used to work fine before but now when I tried to do this:

```
while php > 0:
    doing = input(print('What will', starter, 'do? '))
    if doing == 'attack':
        php -= randint(1,5) * atk
        hp -= randint(1,5) * patk
```

This used to work just fine but now it says:

```
 line 61, in <module>
    hp -= randint(1,5) * patk
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'function' and 'int'
```

and I don't know what to do. Is it maybe because a function shares the name with an int(hp)?

Comment: I think your `hp` is not a number but instead is a function. Do a `print(repr(hp))` and report back with the result.

Comment: Yes, you were right. After experimenting a bit more I realised that if I changed the name of the function it worked normally. Thank you.